# App Preview Quicktime iPhone 6

Tags: iphone, video

I recorded an iPhone 6 video with Quicktime. When I save the file, the resolution is 640 x 1136.

How do I save it in 750 x 1334, the iPhone 6 screen size?

Comment: You mean in a custom iOS App, or in computer?

Comment: iOS App, recorded on MacBook via Firewire with Quicktime.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling zoom mode solved the problem. Settings > Display & Brightness > Display Zoom, then select Zoomed. After you device restarts it will capture screen video in 750 x 1334 resolution.